# Socket Accept() blocking until I press a key

Tags: c#, sockets, server

My program will stop at the `Accept()` for a blocking wait, and it will start a new thread for handling the accepted socket.

However, sometimes the client successfully connect to the server and sends data,
I use a packet sniffer tool checked that server had been received the data,
but my server program stop until I press an Enter key;

After I press the enter key all of the data which has been send before will be process.

But I don't have any `Console.Read()` in my program.

Here is my code:

```
static Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
public static int Main(String[] args)
{
    listener.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;
    listener.SendTimeout = 10000;
    listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
    listener.ReceiveBufferSize = 51200;
    listener.SendBufferSize = 1283;
    listener.Listen(30); 
    while(true) {
       Socket clientSocket = listener.Accept();
       Console.WriteLine("Connection Success");
       var thread = new Thread(() => StartListening(clientSocket)) {
            IsBackground = true
        };
        thread.Start();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code does not display the behavior you describe. Show the `StartListening()` method also.

Comment: I don't want to ask smart, but why do you even use `Accept`? `BeginAccept` would be better.

Comment: @CodeCaster hello , my program even not display the "Connection Success" word when it's jamming, I think it is not the problem point, so I didn't post the code in StartListening(),I can post that if you think that is really necessary

Comment: @Joshua Bakker Thank for your suggest , I will try that way.

Comment: Please, post all the code that you are using to handle the client connection, this code is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I click the console,the console will turn to a Select mode like this :

[Select mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSH7X.jpg)

All the function will be stopped, so I close the "QuickEdit Mode" in the setting of  commend window , then the problem seems to be solved.

[setting page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUEfX.jpg)